# How can i pass string variable to the first textbox in another program in Java

Tags: java, string, variables, textbox

I used the following in Java using Eclipse to run a program by the Runtime command below:

```
String[] cmd = { "C:\\Program Files\\Windows Live\\Messenger\\msnmsgr.exe",first,third };
```

notice that first,third are both String variables, now when this command runs the program I want to pass both of them into 2 textboxes. I want these string to be copied into the program i ran textboxes like here. only i need this one thing, how can i pass the strings, and why some of the users told me to use this code to pass the string variables, is it a pointer problem?

Comment: Huh?  What text boxes?  What code do you have? What are you trying to do?

Comment: listen buddy, i learned C# lang for about 2 yrs, now i in the beginning of Java, so would you help me or not? peace out.. thank you anyway

Comment: Whoa, I asked for clarification on your question in order to help find an answer.  I really don't appreciate your attitude here, and don't expect to get help from others if you're not willing to cooperate.

Comment: sorry, but when you said "Huh?" i thought you are mocking me (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot do that, unless you can pass the arguments in through the command line you have no way of interacting with a separate program's interface.

Comment: no, but i did that in C#... thank you for respond... maybe you are trying to say so cause you know this is the way viruses behave hahaha like our computers teacher in high school (;

Comment: How did you do it in C#?  In general, there's no way for one program to control the UI of another.  You have to *know* something about the program you're controlling, and that program has to be written to expect being controlled in this manner.  If you've done it in C#, then you should be able to do something similar in Java (though you may need some additional libraries to interact with an alien process like this).